# Mutually cancelling Tasks

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Here is a little test bed showing two Tasks that start at the same time, and whichever completes first cancels the other:

```
func startTest() async throws {
    Task { await test() }
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
    // comment out this next line to test the timeout
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init("Test"), object: nil)
}

func test() async {
    let notificationTask = Task {
        for await _ in NotificationCenter.default
            .notifications(named: .init("Test"), object: nil)
            .prefix(1) {}
        print("Done waiting for the notification")
    }
    let timeoutTask = Task {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
        notificationTask.cancel()
        print("I timed out and cancelled the notification task")
    }
    await notificationTask.value
    timeoutTask.cancel()
    print("finished!")
}
```

As you can see, the idea is that either we receive the notification within 5 seconds, in which case the five second timer is cancelled, or we time out in 5 seconds, in which case waiting for the notification is cancelled.

My question is: is there a neater way to express this? I tried various task group and async let formulations but didn't come up with anything. Maybe this is the "right" way but it grates somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a [`TaskGroup`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup)
2. Add all your "racing" tasks to it (they can be more than 2!)
3. Call [`await tg.next()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/next()) to wait for the result of the "race winner"
4. Call [`tg.cancelAll()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup/cancelall()) to cancel the outstanding tasks
5. ???
6. profit!

```swift
import Foundation

func startTest() async throws {
    Task { try await test() }
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
    // comment out this next line to test the timeout
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .init("Test"), object: nil)
}


func test() async throws {
    try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask { // formerlynotificationTask
            for await _ in NotificationCenter.default
                .notifications(named: .init("Test"), object: nil)
                .prefix(1) {}
            print("Done waiting for the notification")
        }
        
        group.addTask { // formerly "timeoutTask"
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)
            print("I timed out and cancelled the notification task")
        }
        
        try await group.next() // Wait for the first completed task
        group.cancelAll() // Cancel the rest
    }
    print("finished!")
}

try await startTest()
```

Comment: Good but it crashes on the `try!` if the notification is the first to arrive.

Comment: I think the solution here is to make this a throwing task group. We can then just say `try`. Another nice touch is that in the first task we can check `Task.isCancelled` and print different things to prove that we did or didn't get cancelled.

Comment: It think we're all just a bit quick to assume a `sleep` can't fail :D (A lesson I need to keep in mind for the future.)

Comment: Actually just changing `try!` to `try?` works fine for me.

Comment: But, the general observation is to never use `try!` (unless you really want it to treat it as a fatal error).

Comment: @RobNapier – Lol. IMHO, more disturbing than the fact that some might overlook that [`sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)/) throws `CancellationError` is the problem that folks forget to follow this pattern in their own cancelable code (i.e., people who check `Task.isCancelled` frequently neglect to throw `CancellationError` in that situation).

Comment: Heya gents. Indeed, using a throwing task group is the answer. I shortcutted using `try!` while I figured out the other details, but forgot to come back to it. Someone downvoted though lol, which entirely ancillary to the to the actual idea of the solution (and which has a trivial & obvious fix). Fixed!

Comment: Although in my real use case I'm going to use `try?` because the implications of turning this into a throwing task group, as the resulting `try` and `throws` echo all the way back through the call chain, are unspeakable.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Alexander answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77046099/1271826) your question (+1), but just a few thoughts:

1. I know you are inclined to use `try?` within `test` to avoid throwing errors, but I might suggest that the idiomatic behavior is a throwing pattern, where you throw an error if it timed out, but not if it didn’t. That way, a caller can detect which path was executed, but the caller can `try?` if you really want to throw away the success vs. failure information.

   Now, I freely acknowledge that you do not currently need it to `throw` (and deal with the concomitant handling that entails), but I might suggest that it is the caller that should be making that decision (e.g., with `try? await test()`), not the `test` function itself.
2. Before I go to alternatives, I would like to revisit the original example. Consider this rendition:

   ```swift
   func testWithTasks() async throws {
       let notificationTask = Task {
           for await _ in NotificationCenter.default
               .notifications(named: .test, object: nil)
               .prefix(1)
           {
               logger.debug("\(#function) Received notification")
           }
           try Task.checkCancellation()
       }

       let timeoutTask = Task {
           try await Task.sleep(for: timeoutDuration)
           notificationTask.cancel()
           logger.debug("\(#function) Timed out and canceled the notification task")
       }

       try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
           try await notificationTask.value
           timeoutTask.cancel()
       } onCancel: {
           notificationTask.cancel()
           timeoutTask.cancel()
       }

       logger.debug("\(#function) finished!")
   }
   ```

   - With `withTaskCancellationHandler`, the caller now has the ability to cancel this function itself. Again, you might not need that at this point, but it is simple to fix and is good practice. I know you know this, but for the sake of future readers, we should be wary using unstructured concurrency unless we add this sort of handling.
   - The `notificationTask` should `checkCancellation` … In the original rendition, if the notification task was canceled, the `AsyncSequence` would canceled, but it would behave as if the notification came in; we want this to not only exit the `for`-`await`-`in`, but also report if it was an early exit due to cancelation;
3. Moving to the task group rendition, it might look like:

   ```swift
   func testWithGroup() async throws {
       try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
           group.addTask {
               for await _ in NotificationCenter.default
                   .notifications(named: .test, object: nil)
                   .prefix(1)
               {
                   logger.debug("Received the notification")
               }
               try Task.checkCancellation()
           }

           group.addTask {
               try await Task.sleep(for: timeoutDuration)
               logger.debug("I timed out and cancelled the notification task")
               throw CancellationError()                            // make sure to throw error so group can recognize
           }

           try await group.next()                                   // Wait for the first completed task
           group.cancelAll()                                        // Cancel the rest
       }
       logger.debug("\(#function) finished!")
   }
   ```

   This is similar to Alexander’s rendition except (a) the `checkCancellation` in the `notificationTask`, as noted above; and (b) the `timeoutTask` actually throws a `CancellationError` in order to inform the task group that has been canceled. The combination of these two achieves the idiomatic behavior that the “happy path” does not throw errors, but timeout does.

   This approach has the virtue of remaining within structured concurrency. But at the same time, it is reliant on some subtle task group behaviors. I personally would favor the prior `Task`-based approach, as it looks less brittle to my eye, but I understand the attraction of the task group approach.
4. Another approach would be to abstract out the “timeout” logic. E.g.:

   ```swift
   func testWithTimeoutSequence() async throws {
       for try await value in NotificationCenter.default
            .notifications(named: .test, object: nil)
            .prefix(1)
            .timeout(timeoutDuration)
       {
           logger.debug("\(#function) Received notification: \(value)")
       }

       logger.debug("\(#function) finished!")
   }
   ```

   Now this `timeout(_:)` could wrap this logic in its own type (in the spirit of [SE-0298 Async Sequence: AsyncSequence-to-AsyncSequence](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0298-asyncsequence.md#asyncsequence-to-asyncsequence)). Or easier, just use an `AsyncStream`:

   ```swift
   extension AsyncSequence where Self: Sendable {
       func timeout(_ duration: Duration) -> AsyncThrowingStream<Element, Error> {
           AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
               let sequenceTask = Task {
                   do {
                       for try await value in self {
                           continuation.yield(value)
                       }
                       try Task.checkCancellation()
                       continuation.finish()
                   } catch {
                       continuation.finish(throwing: error)
                   }
               }

               let timeoutTask = Task {
                   try await Task.sleep(for: duration)
                   sequenceTask.cancel()
               }

               continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                   sequenceTask.cancel()
                   timeoutTask.cancel()
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Now, this pattern assumes that the asynchronous sequence elements are `Sendable` (and notifications ain’t, at least not yet), but it is a more generalized approach to timeout logic with sequences.

(Please forgive the tactical changes in the above, e.g., `Logger`, the notification name static, etc.)